# Powershell hashtable in quotes

Tags: powershell, hashmap

In Powershell, I have a hashtable called $derivedkey with 2 key-value pairs.

I want to use the values in my hash table inside a double quote like this:

```
write-host "mysalt = $derivedkey['salt']"
```

But what I get back is:

```
mysalt = System.Collections.Hashtable['salt']
```

Is there a way such that I can get powershell to evaluate the hashmap to the value, so it will return this?

```
mysalt = F668844CD184B7549E00DCBE51274730
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it in a sub-expression like this:

```
write-host "mysalt = $($derivedkey['salt'])"
```

Otherwise it stops as soon as the end of a valid variable name is reached, and ['salt'] is not a part of the variable name, so it's trying to interpret the entire hashtable not just the 'salt' entry.

Answer (score 3):

Since I find having all those $ signs and parenthesis painful, I use the string formatters:

```
"mysalt = {0}" -f $derivedkey['salt'] | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subexpression `$()` to expand an expression(not a variable) in a string. Try:

```
write-host "mysalt = $($derivedkey['salt'])"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple concatenation.

```
"mysalt = " + $derivedkey['salt'] | write-host
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this so it sounds less like a quesion?

Answer (score 0):

Write-Host uses quotes, and quotes take strings as input. A hashtable is not a string, so you have to tell PS to expand its contents before parsing it as a string.

This also happens when dealing with integers and objects in general. For these cases I personally use one of 3 options:

##### 1. Subexpression

```
Write-Host "mysalt = $($derivedkey['salt'])"
```

The *$(...)* syntax is a subexpression, which means the content within is evaluated first by PS independently of the quotes around it. I like this approach when I want to maintain continuity in the string for code legibility, like in a path, e.g., `"C:/users/me/Programs/$app/$($versionDict[$version])/$lang/lang.xml"`

##### 2. Concatenation

```
Write-Host ( 'mysalt = ' + $derivedkey['salt'] )
```

Notice there are no quotes around our hashtable here, so PS doesn't try to evaluate it as a string and instead expands it normally. The + symbol links the non-string to the string. The parentheses concatenate all the contents within, and write-host outputs the concatenated object. You can concatenate any number of items in this manner in PowerShell.

Concatenation emphasizes variable visibility in the code, and with tab indentation to align common themes, I find it creates more legible code over multiple lines:

```
Write-Host ( "`n" + 'mysalt  = '    +    $derivedkey['salt']    +    'from key  = '   +    $key    )
Write-Host ( "`t" + 'forFile = '    +    $filename              +    'in folder = '   +    $folder )
```

Just be aware that you have to cast integers to strings using the `(<someNumber>).ToString()` method.

##### 3. Here-String

```
Write-Host @"
mysalt = $($myDict['salt'])
"@
```

This is technically the same thing as option 1, as it involves injecting a subexpression into a string, but it's easier to format multi-line string output in the console.

The Write-Host is usually optional for a here-string, but from within a function call it might be necessary if you want the console output.

There are other ways of doing this as the other answers have shown. These are just my approaches that I find most intuitive.